# When the user inputs a number, show a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a store where users are able to search by either entering the product title, or searching for the product SKU. We'd like to show a prompt to users who enter a number into the search box to give them a bit of info on searching for SKUs.

Example: Searching for Polo, nothing happens. Searching for GD459, a box appears giving info.

I've seen lots of answers on SO that detect whether the entire thing is a number, or whether it's text - but not both.

I know that to detect as the user types, I should be doing the following:

```js
$("form input").keyup(function(){
    // presumably an if statement?    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/search" method="get" class="input-group search-bar" role="search" >
  <input type="search" name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" placeholder="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" class="input-group-field" aria-label="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}">
  <br>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button type="submit" class="btn icon-fallback-text">
   <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="fallback-text">{{ 'general.search.submit' | t  }}</span>
 </button>
  </span>
</form>
```

I appreciate that's not a whole lot of code to go off, but a general point in the right direction would really help.

Comment: Have you considered to use an autocomplete solution that targets this SKU field in the db?

Comment: It might help to understand the structure of the SKU code. Is it always 2 chars followed by 3 digits? What shall happen if I search for Polo4 (contains also a number)?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$("form input").keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) && this.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        alert('Letters and numbers!');
    } else {
        // Not letters and numbers
    }
}
```

If you have a specific SKU format you could refine it further, e.g. 2 Letters plus 4-8 numbers:

```
$("form input").keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4,8}$/)) {
        alert('Match');
    } else {
        // No match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your string into constituent parts using `.split()` then loop through these parts and test for a number;

```
$("form input").keyup(function(){

    const stringArray = $(this).val().split("");
    let isNumeric = false;

    $(stringArray).each(function(i,v){ //i = index, v = value at that index
        if(!isNaN(v))
        {
            isNumeric = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (isNumeric)
        alert("Yay it's got a number in it");
});
```